# 3D vector field in gnuplot with specified colors

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to plot a 3D vector field in gnuplot where every vector is a specified color. My input file looks like this:

| x | y | z | dx | dy | dz | color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x1 | y1 | z1 | dx1 | dy1 | dz1 | color1 (hex code) |

and so forth. I tried the following code, piggybacking off the solution*

```
scale = 1
splot 'file.dat' u 1:2:3:($4*scale):($5*scale):($6*scale):7 w vectors arrowstyle 1 lc rgb var
```

but this gave me a color bar on the side of the graph. Also, every vector was colored gray, instead of the color in the input file. Could someone suggest a fix for this?

* [Vector field 3D plot in gnuplot with contour of vectors (bottom)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44133274/vector-field-3d-plot-in-gnuplot-with-contour-of-vectors-bottom)

Comment: What exactly do the colors in column 7 look like?  Your plot command looks to me that it should work if the values are of the form 0xRRGGBB.  Is that what you have?

Comment: Hi Ethan, thank you for your reply. Yes, that's exactly what they look like. I have 0xFF0000 for red, and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command is very nearly correct.  The problem is that apparently the line color is considered part of the arrow style, so the program produces an error message *duplicated or contradicting arguments in plot options* if you give both an arrow style and a line color.  If you move the `lc rgb variable` to the style definition, it is accepted. This works for me:

```
set style arrow 1 filled head lc rgb variable
plot DATA using 1:2:3:4:5:6:7 with vectors arrowstyle 1
```